# Zend redirect not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have following configuration in module.config.php

```
'router'=>array(
        'routes'=>array(
                'test'=>array(
                        'type'=>'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                        'options'=>array(
                                'route'=>'/test',
                                'defaults'=>array(
                                        'controller'=>'Test\Controller\Index',
                                        'action'=>'index'
                                )
                        ),
                        'may_terminate' => true,
                        'child_routes' => array(
                                'edit' => array(
                                        'type' => 'segment',
                                        'options' => array(
                                                'route' =>'/edit[/:id]',
                                                'constraints' =>array('id' => '[\d\w\-_]*'),
                                                'defaults' => array(
                                                        'controller' =>'Test\Controller\Index',
                                                        'action' => 'edit',
                                                ),
                                        ),
                                ),
                                'add' => array(
                                        'type' => 'segment',
                                        'options' => array(
                                                'route' =>'/add',
                                                'defaults' => array(
                                                        'controller' =>'Test\Controller\Index',
                                                        'action' => 'add',
                                                ),
                                        ),
                                ),
                        ),
                )
        )
)
```

now I am using following redirect

return $this->redirect()->toRoute('test');

and it is not working. I am not getting what is wrong with this

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". Are you getting any errors? Is the page shown normally? Do you get an empty page? We need more information.

Comment: I am redirecting page after calling save function. Function is executed properly. Fields are reflected in DB. But browser shows the same page, it is not redirected to desired location.

Comment: Okay. Can you show us the actual code? The configuration is not very helpful to us.

Comment: what exactly you would like to see, I am using redirect in loop edit action

Answer (score 0):

Your Config file is not much helpful here, you should have posted your controller's code, nevertheless ,

instead of `return $this->redirect()->toRoute('test');`,

use the following format

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('ModuleName',
  array('controller'=>controllerName,
        'action' => actionName,
        'params' =>params));
```

Where `ModuleName` is the name of your `module`,
Where `ControllerName` is the name of your `controller`,
Where `Action` Name is the name of your `action`,

Note:- `params` are optional.

Answer (score 0):

If you module name is test, then you try with:

```
return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/test');
```